Late 70s/early 80s sci-fi/horror comic with a story about a pair of colonists and another about a group of friends kidnapped by a circus or freak show
I am trying to locate the title and issue number of a science fiction/fantasy/horror comic book. It was an issue I purchased sometime between 1977-1983. Two of the stories were as follows:

Sci-fi/horror pregnancy story - a female colonist falls in love with a male colonist. They marry with the understanding that they can never consummate. They move to his home colony, where she witnesses him with a native woman. In jealousy, she tricks him. She wakes up in the jungle with a very rapidly progressing pregnancy. He arrives and kills her just as the monstrosity tears out of her.

Circus Horror story - a group of friends are kidnapped by a creepy traveling circus or freak show. They are slowly and horribly transformed.


The only other things I can remember are that there were several stories in the comic and that the cover of the comic was in green tones.
Can anyone tell me: the title of the comic book, the issue, and, if possible, the titles/authors of these stories? I've been searching for years with no luck. Thank you for any help.

Hmmm. There are a lot of horror comics with anthology-style stories. Can you recall if this was an indie? Or a big two (DC, Marvel) comic - both had horror lines? One writer who was making a lot of these during that time frame was Bruce Jones: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_Tales
